# Possible To Implement A Custom Ref Struct Based Object That Is Span<> Like For Circular Buffer?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I've got a circular buffer and I'd like to be able to create a span, and unfortunately it's not as simple as Span span = m_Buffer.AsSpan(Head, Tail) or even (Head, Tail-Head) depending on the scenario. I'm not exactly an expert in ref structs, I understand their purpose and where they are beneficial but I've never tried to build an implemention my own, so my question would be essentially, is this even possible?

The best answer I've seen to be able to find, without a custom implementation, is using two different spans. I suppose that could do, but I'd like to figure this out.

I could of course simply create a span of the entire circular buffer and check if the index is empty or null, but I would preferably like to have a span the represents the elements in order from head to tail. I'm not sure this is possible because it would seem technically while the memory block they exists in is contiguous, their order of access is not, as one may be 'behind' the other.

Has anyone every run into this scenario and come up with a solution that does not involve the use of two different spans that allows the iteration of current elements within the circular buffer without the ones that are empty? The only suggestion I have so far that seems feasible is a sort of wrapper class for two different spans that acts as a facade for the two allowing me to interact with them as if they are one, which I suppose is fine and dandy, but I was hoping someone might know a little more about the actual fundamentals of ref structs and be able to tell me if my aspirations of a single span-like object, as a custom implementation, to do the job is possible. As I imagine, this facade whatever pseudo-synonymous pattern name we want to call it, would require an object and thus an allocation.

I have a feeling, it'll be a fruitless endeavor. But I figure the dumbest questions are the ones not asked out of fear of anonymous online strangers complaining about them. <3

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in the way you envision it. A Span is represented internally with just a pointer to the data buffer and an element count.

Comment: I suspect you're right, I was just hoping someone would pass through and know something amazing. Right now I'm toying with a readonly ref struct with two spans, that's the best I got at the moment. With the `in` keyword I should be able to deter the defensive copies at least and reduce allocation, I don't know. I'm still very new to the ref structs and a lot of the implementation details we don't have access to because if we wanted to make a pointer with a range we'd need it to be unsafe so there's something going on behind the scenes that I've yet to have the time to dig into.

Comment: The best you can do is a `ref struct` that holds two spans, one of which may be empty. You would always read/write the `first` then the `second`, just keep the start of the circular buffer in the `first`